# Acentuação em C

Tags: c, acentuação

Como faço para acentuar as vogais sem ter que usar a biblioteca locale.h ? Sei que o £ corresponde ao E como seriam para as outras vogais ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente todas as letras, números e caracteres especiais tem uma representação na [tabela  ASCII](http://ic.unicamp.br/~everton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf), está tabela mostra qual seria o binário que representa aquele caractere que você está querendo que o computador imprima ou algo do tipo, deste modo o binário pode ser convertido para octal, hexadecimal e para decimal.

Então sem mais delongas a outra forma de se imprimir um acento ou coisa do tipo sem a biblioteca locale.h seria utilizando a [tabela ASCII](http://ic.unicamp.br/~everton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf).

Ex:

Como mostrado no link o caractere 'ç' é representado pelo decimal 135, então para imprimi-lo basta fazer o seguinte, `printf("%c", 135);`, desta forma o caractere 'ç' será impresso na tela.

Espero ter ajudado ;).